# Is it possible to listen to dynamics CRM 2011 events programatically?

Tags: javascript, dom-events, dynamics-crm-2011

I want to listen to events via external resource and not  via the GUI event tool.

Something like:

```
entity.onSave(myFunc)
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add an onSave event handler via this call:

```
Xrm.Page.data.entity.addOnSave(myFunc)
```

Of course you'll still need to call this code from the OnLoad to wire it up.

You can also do onChange events on attributes as well

```
Xrm.Page.getAttribute(controlName).addOnChange(onChange)
```